# mostrar contenido del DIV según fecha específica

Tags: javascript

Vengo desarrollando el siguiente código js, el cual me devuelve una imagen según el mes actual. Me gustaría mostrar algo según una fecha en especifico: por ejemplo que el día 25 de septiembre a las 00:00 me muestre una imagen, el día 2 de octubre a las 00:00 me muestre una imagen, el día 30 de octubre a las 00:00 me muestre una imagen.

```
function cambie_div(){
hoy = new Date;
mes = (hoy.getMonth())+1;
if(mes==1)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_enero.gif" >')
},
if(mes==2)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_enero.gif" >')
},
if(mes==3)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_enero.gif" >')
},
document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = imagen_seleccionada;
}
cambie_div();
setInterval ("cambie_imagen()", 60000 );
```

---

Muchas gracias por sus criticas constructivas.
estaba confundiendo el php con java, trato de crear algo y aun soy nivel amateur, me falta mucho por leer.
al final el codigo quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
function cambiarDiv(){
hoy = new Date();
mes = hoy.getMonth()+1;
dia = hoy.getDate();


if(mes==1)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_enero.gif" >')
}
else if(mes==1 && dia==4)
{
document.write('<IMG SRC="imagen_enero_dia4.gif" >')
}

 document.getElementById("mes");
}
cambiarDiv();
setInterval ("cambiarDiv()", 60000 );
```

me funciona para lo que deseo agregar segun el mes...
tengo otra curiosidad...

existe otra manera de cambiar contenido de un div, segun una fecha especifica (pasa que quiero agregar un codigo html mas extenso: por ejemplo

```
 '            <div class="map">'+
'                <div class="map_country">'+
'                    <div class="flag">'+
'                        <span>PERÚ</span>'+
'       <img src="images/banderas/circu/peru.png" alt="Perú">'+
'                    </div>'+
'                <div>'+
'                <div class="city">'+
'                    <span>Trujillo</span>'+
'                </div>'+
'                <div class="coordes">'+
'                    <p class="cc">-7.1214,-8.474272</p>'+
'                    <div class="copy">Copiar CC</div>'+
'                </div>'+
'                </div>'+
```

Comment: `new Date()`, te faltan los paréntesis. En JS las funciones se deberían declarar en *camelCase* no *snake_case*, esto no es un error, pero es convención y facilita la lectura del código. Y sobre todo... si llamas a tu función `cambie_div` no puedes llamarle `cambie_imagen()` en el `setInterval`(fíjate como setInterval no lleva guión, como ya dije, las funciones se nombran en camelCase). Además, el `setInterval`  pide un handler en su primer parámetro, no un string -> `setInterval(cambie_div, 60000)`.

Comment: Por otro lado... parece que has copiado y pegado código de varias partes sin entender lo que haces, porque hay dos cosas diferentes en marcha en tu código. Por un lado, añades cosas al html con `document.write` y por otro intentas machacar el innerHtml de `mes` con lo guardado en `imagen_seleccionada`... pero esa variable no la veo definida en ningún lugar. Qué se supone que tiene?? No deberías guardar la imagen ahí en los `if` en vez de usar el `document.write`? Tampoco tiene sentido tener las comas al final de las llaves de los `if (...) {...},` <- esa coma ahí es un error...

Comment: gracias por tus consejos @Benito-B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Antes que nada, ten en cuenta los comentarios de @Benito-B, no los estoy aplicando todos ya que quiero enfocarme en la forma de mostrar algo diferente según el mes o el día del mes

En este ejemplo genérico cambié todos los `document.write` por `console.log` para mostrar el funcionamiento y tendrás que adaptarlo a tus necesidades

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar `switch` o `if` para los meses y adentro de los meses puedes utilizar otro `switch` o `if` para comparar el día. El día del mes lo puedes obtener con `getDate()`

También podrías utilizar una variable para guardar el valor de la imagen que desees mostrar y únicamente utilizar `document.write()` o en el caso del ejemplo `console.log()` una sola vez (Así el código se ve un poco más limpio)

**Nota:** También comenté la siguiente línea ya que no agregaste HTML

```
document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = img;
```

En el ejemplo si cambias la fecha puedes ver que en la consola se escribe la "imagen" del mes correspondiente y si pones en la fecha el 2 de octubre va a mostrar algo diferente a los demás días del mes de octubre

```js
function cambie_div(){
hoy = new Date('2022-10-02');
mes = hoy.getMonth()+1;
dia = hoy.getDate();

switch(mes){
    case 1:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_enero.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 2:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_febrero.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 3:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_marzo.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 4:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_abril.gif" >';
    break;
  
  case 5:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_mayo.gif" >';
    break;
  
  case 6:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_junio.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 7:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_julio.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 8:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_agosto.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 9:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_septiembre.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 10:
    switch(dia) {
        case 2:
        img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_2_octubre.gif" >';
        break;
      default:
        img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_octubre.gif" >';
        break;
    }
    break;
    
  case 11:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_noviembre.gif" >';
    break;
    
  case 12:
    img = '<IMG SRC="imagen_diciembre.gif" >';
    break;
}
console.log(img);

//document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = img;
}
cambie_div();
setInterval ("cambie_imagen()", 60000 );
```

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato